# How to use both a uri and passed in parameters for a linked template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Say you have the following files, these where made in a visual studio by selecting a new Azure resource group deployment then adding a nested template twice

azuredeploy.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "_artifactsLocation": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
      "type": "securestring"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "linkedTemplateTemplateFolder": "nestedtemplates",
    "linkedTemplateTemplateFileName": "linkedTemplate.json",
    "linkedTemplateTemplateParametersFileName": "linkedTemplate.parameters.json"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "linkedTemplate",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri":
            "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('linkedTemplateTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('linkedTemplateTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parametersLink": {
          "uri":
            "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('linkedTemplateTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('linkedTemplateTemplateParametersFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "_artifactsLocation": { "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocation')]" },
          "_artifactsLocationSasToken": { "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]" }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "result": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": "[reference('linkedTemplate').outputs.result.value]"
    }
  }
}
```

azuredeploy.parameters.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
  }
}
```

nestedtemplates\linkedTemplate.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "Foo": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "_artifactsLocation": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
      "type": "securestring"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "thirdTeirTemplateFolder": "nestedtemplates",
    "thirdTeirTemplateFileName": "thirdTeir.json",
    "thirdTeirTemplateParametersFileName": "thirdTeir.parameters.json"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "thirdTeir",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('thirdTeirTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('thirdTeirTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "Foo": {"value": "[parameters('Foo')]"} 
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "result": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference('thirdTeir').outputs.result]"
    } 
  }
}
```

nestedtemplates\linkedTemplate.parameters.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "Foo": {
      "value": "Foo!"
    } 
  }
}
```

nestedtemplates\thirdTeir.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "Foo": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "result": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('Foo')]"
    } 
  }
}
```

This will naturally fail with the error

> Error: Code=InvalidDeployment; Message=The deployment 'linkedTemplate' cannot have both the ParameterLink and Parameter property set. Please use one or the other. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.

and that makes perfect sense because [the documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/deployments#deploymentproperties-object) you can't use both `parametersLink` and `parameters` at the same time.

What workaround should I do in this situation, how to i get `_artifactsLocation` and `_artifactsLocationSasToken` passed in to the middle tier of templates while still allowing a separate file to hold configuration values that will be passed in?

Just in case I am asking a XY Question, the real problem I am trying to solve is if there is some way to just read directly in a json file that holds some configuration data passed in via uri and access its content? That is real thing I need to do.

Comment: Link to a copy of the question on the [social.msdn.microsoft.com forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/518943d1-2d06-4393-b3b9-f6ea5144717c/how-to-use-both-a-uri-and-passed-in-parameters-from-inside-a-arm-template?forum=azurescripting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the root problem you're trying to get around is passing both parameters and linked parameters to a nested deployment...  I can think of a few options, none are very elegant:

1. have your deployment script read the linked json file params and use all params in the nested deployment
2. have your deployment script write your param files with the location and sasToken before staging them
3. write the location and sasToken to a deployment output, and reference them from the output rather than as a parameter
4. write the location and sasToken to keyvault and put the parameter reference to keyvault in your linked param file - this is tricky since you'd have to know the vault reference before deployment (when you create your param file).

3 is probably the least hacky and could be done completely within the template(s) but might make your sasToken no longer secret.  (I think, not sure if you can leave it secureString throughout or not).

That help?